# UWP:- How to create drag UI (indicating where the items are to be dropped) while dragging items?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a drag UI of something like in the below screenshot. If I set AllowDrop in my listview to "true", it automatically opens up spaces to give room for the dragged items to drop. But, I'm more keen on giving a UI indicating stating "drop here" instead of spaces.

How can I create of something like in the below with placeholders indication when I move over the dragged item?

Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How can I create of something like in the below with placeholders indication when I move over the dragged item?

For your requirement, you could use `ListView` Footer to realize this feature, and process Footer `Collapsed` property in the `DragOver` and `Drop` event handler. Please refer the following code.

```
private  void TargetListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Our list only accepts text
    e.AcceptedOperation = (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text)) ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Inside", true);
}


private async void TargetListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {

        var def = e.GetDeferral();
        var s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
        var items = s.Split('\n');
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            _selection.Add(item);
        }
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Outside", true);
        def.Complete();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListView
    x:Name="TargetListView"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="8,4"
    AllowDrop="True"
    CanDragItems="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    DragItemsCompleted="TargetListView_DragItemsCompleted"
    DragItemsStarting="TargetListView_DragItemsStarting"
    DragOver="TargetListView_DragOver"
    Drop="TargetListView_Drop"
    >
    <ListView.Footer>
        <Border Background="DarkGray" Opacity="0.8">
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Footer"
                Height="44"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                FontSize="25"
                Text="Please Place your item"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                />
        </Border>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>


<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragDropGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="Outside" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Inside">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="Footer.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Op posted uservoice below, if anyone think this helpful please vote it up.

[**Allowing custom air drop UI while dragging items of a ListView**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/38072578-allowing-custom-air-drop-ui-while-dragging-items-o)

Comment: Thank you @Nico... But this works only if the drop point is at the footer... Is there a way to replicate the same behavior across the item templates as well... Some thing like in the above screenshot

Comment: emm, It's hard to design, but you could use mvvm bind to insert temp item("Placeholder text") when dragover and remove it when drop.

Comment: Ohh okay @Nico..Thank you... I tried inserting temp items but the look and feel is not good... When the items are dragged vertically within the listview, the placeholders are not reflecting immediately

Comment: Yep, I think this is good feature request that allow user custom drop air style, Please feel free post on UserVoice.

Comment: Sure. I will raise a request .. Thank you @Nico

Comment: You are welcome, if you have posted please share link for me, I will add to the above reply and hope more developers vote up your voice, And if the answer is helpful please mark it thx.

Comment: Sure. Here, I've the request link:- https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/38072578-allowing-custom-air-drop-ui-while-dragging-items-o